# Socket.io Server in Delphi XE5

Tags: delphi, socket.io

Im looking for sample source code, component for Socket.io Server implementation. I'm using SgcWebsockets (http://websockets.esegece.com/) works fine like socket.io client, they don't provide socket.io component, there is some solution or aproach..

Im supporting Web app (AngularJS) that use nodejs has main socket.io server in the cloud, but when something goes wrong the web app redirect the traffic to the local app server builded in Dephi, the http server indy, websocket-Socket.io client component works fine, but now we need also implement the socket.io server locally.

Comment: Hi for what you need socket - for tcp comunication? In delphi you have TTCpClient, TTcpServer, TIdTCPClient, TIdTCPServer... Use it

Comment: Im supporting Web app that use nodejs has main socket.io server in the cloud , but when something goes wrong the web app redirect the traffic to the local app server builded in Dephi , the http server , websocket-Socket.io client component works fine, but Now we need also implement the socket.io server locally

Answer (score 2):

My websockets library has support for socket.io:
https://github.com/andremussche/DelphiWebsockets

Comment: looks nice , im trying to test your library but ask me about uROIndyHTTPServer library this is RemObject library right?, Can i use Indy ? im using Delphi xe5 ... Thanks!!

Comment: @user3461347 you can ignore uROIndyHTTPServer, but if you have RemObjects then you can use this one for RemObjects too. You should  use IdWebsocketServer.pas for normal indy + websocket + socket.io.

Comment: Hello! , thanks for your response, im using and testing your library, im experiencing some issues with socke.io session id , i can't get that , well , the library sgcWebsocket the Websocket client socket.io implementation raise the error ' No session id on socket io' ... Thanks Again. but i almost there i think.

Comment: @JavierDonosoV it is possible that they use the latest socket.io protocol, whereas my component uses an older spec...